# how to filter data using controller angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have 3 pages 1st page samsunghome which contains listof checkbox with samsung mobile services.2nd page nokiahome which contains listof checkbox with nokia  services.3rd page list of both samsung and nokia stores.if user comes from samsunghome and selected some services i need to show only samsung stores with that particular services.if user comes from nokiahome and selected some services i need to show only nokia stores with that particular services.i have search box also and when i comes from 1st and 2nd pages list page should show selected store with selected services.i have done some logic but its not working listing controller i need to check both selected store and selected services some one help me out

```js
.controller('SamsungServicesCtrl', function ($scope,$filter,$location) {
   var service = ["Regular Service", "Settings Faults", "Software Faults", "Hardware Faults"];
   var services = ["General services", "If a phone doesn’t switch-on, it is called a dead phone, SIM card does not get detected", "Hardware Faults"];
   var icons = ["images/arrow.svg","images/arrow.svg","images/arrow.svg"];
     $scope.items= [] ;
        for(var i=0;i<service.length;i++)
         {
          var modal = {
           name:service[i],
           subname:services[i],
           icon:icons[i],
           selected:false
               }; 
                   
                $scope.items.push(modal);        
         }
            scope.check = function()
            {
                  var checkedItems = [];
                   for(var i=0;i<$scope.items.length;i++){
                      if($scope.items[i].selected){
                         checkedItems.push($scope.items[i].name);
                         }
                        }
               //$location.path('menulisting/listing');
                        var model ="samsung";
    //i have checked Regular Service, Settings Faults
    $location.path('menulisting/listing').search({filter: model +','+checkedItems});
             }
         
})
Nokia service controller
.controller('NokiaServicesCtrl', function ($scope,$filter,$location) {
var service = ["Regular Service", "Settings Faults", "Software Faults", "Hardware Faults"];
var services = ["General services", "If a phone doesn’t switch-on, it is called a dead phone, SIM card does not get detected", "Hardware Faults"];
var icons = ["images/arrow.svg","images/arrow.svg","images/arrow.svg"];
     $scope.items= [] ;
        for(var i=0;i<service.length;i++)
         {
    var modal = {
          name:service[i],
          subname:services[i],
          icon:icons[i],
          selected:false
          }; 
                   
                $scope.items.push(modal);        
         }
   scope.check = function()
            {
                var checkedItems = [];
                for(var i=0;i<$scope.items.length;i++){
                if($scope.items[i].selected){
                checkedItems.push($scope.items[i].name);
                }
              }
                $location.path('menulisting/listing');
            }
         
})
listing controller
.controller('ListingCtrl', [
'$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$filter','$ionicPopover','$ionicLoading',
function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $filter, $ionicPopover, $ionicLoading) {
$scope.$watch(function() {
 return window.localStorage.getItem("searchstore")
 },
 function(searchstore) {
 $scope.query = searchstore;
  console.log($scope.query);
});

$scope.clearSearch = function() {
    window.localStorage.setItem("searchstore", "");
};
 $http.get('****').success(function(data,dealers,response)
       {  
   var filter= $location.search().filter;
   console i am getting
   //samsung,Regular Service, Settings Faults
   $scope.dealers=[];
   for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var temp=data[i].S_Store.split(',');
    for(var j=0;j<temp.length:j++){
     if(temp[j]===filter)
        $scope.dealers.push(data[i]);
     }
    }
           
        });
}])
.filter('customFil', function () {

    return function (dealers, query) {
        var obj = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < dealers.length; i++)
        {
            var tokenisedString =query.split(",");
            var isPresent=false;
for(var j=0;j<tokenisedString.length;j++)
{
                if (dealers[i].S_Services.toUpperCase().includes(tokenisedString[j].toUpperCase())) {
               obj.push(dealers[i]);
                    break;
                   
        }
   
}
               
        }
        return obj;
    }
});
console i am getting like this
1: Object
$$hashKey: "object:28"
Dealer_id: "55b24172c7d354f30cda0e7f"
Legal_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store"
S_Address: Object
address_line1: "No.80, Marks Road"
area: "madiwala"
city: "Bangalore"
state: "Karnataka"
zipcode: "560068"
S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z"
S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com"
S_Store: "samsung"
Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store"
S_Services:"Regular Service,Settings Faults,Software Faults,Hardware Faults"
Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles"
Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles"
2: Object
$$hashKey: "object:28"
Dealer_id: "55b24172c7d354f30cda0e7g"
Legal_Name: "sri shakthi mobile services"
S_Address: Object
address_line1: "3rd street"
area: "madiwala"
city: "Bangalore"
state: "Karnataka"
zipcode: "560068"
S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z"
S_Email_id: "rajs@gmail.com"
S_Store: "nokia"
Store_Name: "sri shakthi mobile service"
S_Services:"Regular Service,Settings Faults,Software Faults,Hardware Faults"
Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles"
Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles"
3: Object
$$hashKey: "object:28"
Dealer_id: "55b24172c7d354f30cda0e7h"
Legal_Name: "sun mobile service center"
S_Address: Object
address_line1: "23rd main ,2nd cross"
area: "madiwala"
city: "Bangalore"
state: "Karnataka"
zipcode: "560068"
S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z"
S_Email_id: "sprtive23@gmail.com"
S_Store: "nokia,samsung"
Store_Name: "sun mobile service center"
S_Services:"Regular Service,Settings Faults,Software Faults,Hardware Faults"
Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles"
Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles"
```

```html
samsung page hml
    <div  ng-controller="SamsungServicesCtrl">
     <ion-content> 

         <li class="item item-checkbox"  ng-repeat="item in items" >
       <img src="{{item.icon}}"  style="float:left;height:30px;width:30px;padding-right:5px;" > 
      <label  class="checkbox checkbox-energized"  >
           <input type="checkbox"  style="float:right;"   ng-model="item.selected"  >
         </label>
      {{item.name}}
       <p style="font-size:10px;  padding-left:0px;">  {{item.subname}}</p>
        </li>
       <div class="padding">
        <button class="button button-full button-energized"  value="submit" ng-click="check()">Apply
     </button>
       </div>
      
     </ion-content>
     </div>

    Nokia Page html
    <div  ng-controller="NokiaServicesCtrl">
     <ion-content> 

         <li class="item item-checkbox"  ng-repeat="item in items" >
       <img src="{{item.icon}}"  style="float:left;height:30px;width:30px;padding-right:5px;" > 
      <label  class="checkbox checkbox-energized"  >
           <input type="checkbox"  style="float:right;"   ng-model="item.selected"  >
         </label>
      {{item.name}}
       <p style="font-size:10px;  padding-left:0px;">  {{item.subname}}</p>
        </li>
       <div class="padding">
        <button class="button button-full button-energized"  value="submit" ng-click="check()">Apply
     </button>
       </div>
      
     </ion-content>
     </div>
    listing page
    <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper" >
        <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query" >
      </label>
    </div>
     <div class="list card"  data-ng-repeat="dealer in dealers || customFil:query" ">
         <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right" href="#">
          <h2>{{dealer.Store_Name}}</h2> 
          <p>{{dealer.S_Address.area}} {{dealer.S_Address.city}}</p> 
         <p>{{dealer.S_Services}}</p>
         </div>  
      </div>
```

i have enclosed my code i want to filter S_Store and S_Services

Comment: you can pass simple filter data as parameters with $location.path, like this: 
$location.path('menulisting/listing'+ params); and in your listing controller recover the paramenters like this: $routeParams.params

Comment: how can i filter from controller. is it possible to filter from controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your conditions for filter as  parameters:

```
$location.path('menulisting/listing').search({model: 'nokia', items:checkedItems});
```

then get these parameters in your controller :

```
var filter = $location.search().model;
var items = $location.search().items;
```

and filter your dealers:

```
$scope.dealers=[];
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var temp=data[i].S_Store.split(',');
    for(var j=0;j<temp.length:j++){
        if(temp[j]===filter){
           data[i].S_Services=items;
           $scope.dealers.push(data[i]);                   
        }
    }
}
```

Notice, that you forgot '$' before scope.check

Comment: console i am getting Cannot read property 'push' of undefined and one more thing i want to check both S_Store and S_Service. also i am having filter text box also.help me out

Comment: I've updated answer. Just add $scope.dealers=[]; before the loop. How can you check S_Service?

Comment: no its not working .it's not filtering it's pusing the checked values to html page

Comment: It's impossible to understand what do you want.

Comment: i really want only matched values of S_Store and S_Services

Comment: example if i select nokia with Regular Service .i need to show matched stores in listing